# Skip items in a list range and continue with the rest

Tags: python, list, loops, skip

I want to print out some items in a list, but I want to skip a couple of items and continue with the rest.

This is an example of my code and how I do it so far.

```
mylist = ["dog","cat","lion","wolf","zebra","monkey","bear","eagle", "bison"]
for item in mylist:
    if item == mylist[4]:
        continue
    if item == mylist[5]:
        continue
    if item == mylist[6]:
        continue
    print(item)
```

How can I do the same thing but without using multiple if statements?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an indexed for-loop (using the index to retrieve the element).

```py
mylist = ["dog", "cat", "lion", "wolf", "zebra", "monkey", "bear", "eagle", "bison"]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if i in [4, 5, 6]:             # element indices to skip
        continue
    print(mylist[i])               # procedures desired
```

The alternative way to do so, is to modify the for-loop range, which would save two lines of code doing `if`. (This is a relatively bad idea)

```py
mylist = ["dog", "cat", "lion", "wolf", "zebra", "monkey", "bear", "eagle", "bison"]

for i in (mylist[:4]+mylist[7:]):  # exclude the skipped ones
    print(mylist[i])               # procedures desired
```

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize a `list comprehension` and remove undesired elements by using their indices.

```
mylist = ["dog", "cat", "lion", "wolf", "zebra", "monkey", "bear", "eagle", "bison"]
out = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(mylist) if i not in [4, 5, 6]]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'wolf', 'eagle', 'bison']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing to get the specific indexes of a list. Try this:

```py
for i in mylist[4:]:
    print(i)
```

This will print all the items after the 4th index. You can also try:

```python
for i in mylist[4:7]:
    print(i)
```

This will print all index 4, 5 and 6

Comment: I think the OP wanted to leave out elements on indexed 4, 5, and 6. You code is not a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

this is just another way to solve it:

```
mylist = ["dog","cat","lion","wolf","zebra","monkey","bear","eagle", "bison"]
banned=[mylist[4],mylist[5],mylist[6]]

#remove all the items that you  don't want before printing
for thing in banned:
    mylist.remove(thing)

#print every element in mylist now:
for animal in mylist:
    print (animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that and one of them is this i write below:

```
mylist = ["dog","cat","lion","wolf","zebra","monkey","bear","eagle", "bison"]
skip_list = [my_list[4],my_list[5],my_list[6]]
for item in mylist:
    if item in skip_list:
        continue
    print(item)
```

here just you need to make a `skip_list` of the items you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```py
mylist = ["dog", "cat", "lion", "wolf", "zebra", "monkey", "bear", "eagle", "bison"]

banned = [mylist[1], mylist[5], mylist[6]]

for item in mylist:
    if item in banned:
        continue
    else:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to skip elements on particular positions or elements with particular contents.
For the former, you can try *list comprehension*,

```py
if item in  [mylist[i] for i in [4,5,6]]:
    continue
```

For the latter, you can just put the elements in a list,

```py
if item in  ["zebra","monkey","bear"]:
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another way to do the same

```py
>>> mylist = ["dog","cat","lion","wolf","zebra","monkey","bear","eagle", "bison"]
>>> del mylist[4:6]
>>> mylist
['dog', 'cat', 'lion', 'wolf', 'bear', 'eagle', 'bison']
```